# What is KEYTOOL in JDK ?and what is use of it as developer?

Tags: java, android

I heard about the keytool which is comes in JDK/bin folder and it is also used in android app when we incorporate our app to Faecbook SDK.so i don't have idea about what keytool is exactly?
can any one help me to introduce the keytool?and where to use it and why to use it?
Thanx in advance

Comment: follow this tutorials : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753522/android-development-keytool-creating-a-keystore

Comment: Have you considered reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)?

Answer (score 1):

> keytool is a key and certificate management utility. It allows users
>   to administer their own public/private key pairs and associated
>   certificates for use in self-authentication (where the user
>   authenticates himself/herself to other users/services) or data
>   integrity and authentication services, using digital signatures. It
>   also allows users to cache the public keys (in the form of
>   certificates) of their communicating peers.
>
> A certificate is a digitally signed statement from one entity (person,
>   company, etc.), saying that the public key (and some other
>   information) of some other entity has a particular value. (See
>   Certificates.) When data is digitally signed, the signature can be
>   verified to check the data integrity and authenticity. Integrity means
>   that the data has not been modified or tampered with, and authenticity
>   means the data indeed comes from whoever claims to have created and
>   signed it.
>
> keytool also enables users to administer secret keys used in symmetric
>   encryption/decryption (e.g. DES).
>
> keytool stores the keys and certificates in a keystore.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)