# What is use of SHA1 Fingerprint in Google API Key?

Tags: android, cryptography

Google's api,facebook's api uses package name of application and SHA1 certificate for their API keys.But how they work? Suppose I have package name 
`com.example.test` and API key is `UIW9934JIO`. So how they ensure that the API key is only restricted to `com.example.test` application. No one can access that key from any other browser or application and how do i implement that type of API key restriction in my application?

Comment: The SDK on the device can check that the APK with package name `com.example.test` was signed with a key having the correct SHA1. Nobody can fake this without knowing the signing key. (At least not with affordable effort)

Comment: Thank for that..But how can i implement with my application and web server that provide API service.I want to protect to only my application.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685124/what-is-sha1-fingerprint